# C# does no copy shotcut file

Tags: c#, copy, shortcut, file-copying

I am using c# and I can copy all kind of files I want but when I want to cop a shortcut or link file c# errors like this :

[image]

this is my code :

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string fileName = "HonarVaMemar.exe";
    string sourcePath = @Application.StartupPath;
    string targetPath = @Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory) + "\\Output HonamrvaMemar Version";

   // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
   string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
   string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

   // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
   // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
   if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
   {
       System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
   }
   System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);


   //-----------------------------------------------------------
   string fileName2 = "HonarVaMemar.exe.lnk";
   string sourceFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName2);
   string destFile2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName2);
   System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile2, destFile2, true);}
```

all other files are copied

.....

Comment: clicking on "Details" might reveal worthwhile information

Answer (score 0):

until you don't post stacktrace or `innerException` it's difficult to answer what exactly happening. I have some guesses

If that shortcut is pointing to some other file (Target property) then while copying that shortcut file may be the target file is not preset at that location.

Or..

May the shortcut file is in use with some other process.

This is just a guess, Please post exception text that you are getting whiling copying.

Answer (score 0):

```
            string fileName = "data.mdb";

            string sourcePath = @Application.StartupPath;
            string targetPath = @"C:\Windows\cat";

            string sourceFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);
            string destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            //if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(targetPath))
            //{
            //    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            //}

            // To copy a file to another location and 

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
```